# How can I avoid Quick Sort stack overflow

Tags: c++, sorting, stack-overflow, quicksort

When I use quick sort in C++, Visual studio 2013 alert a stack overflow error.

How can I fix this problem? In this problem, can't I use this quick sort?

I think because I use recursion in the quick sort, so this problem make many deep memory stack.

here is the code.

```
int partition(int **array, int p, int r){

    int x = array[r][1];
    int i = p - 1;
    int j;
    int temp0, temp1;

    for (j = p; j < r; j++){
        if (array[j][1] <= x){
            i++;

            temp0 = array[i][0];
            temp1 = array[i][1];

            array[i][0] = array[j][0];
            array[i][1] = array[j][1];

            array[j][0] = temp0;
            array[j][1] = temp1;
        }
    }

    temp0 = array[i + 1][0];
    temp1 = array[i + 1][1];

    array[i + 1][0] = array[r][0];
    array[i + 1][1] = array[r][1];

    array[r][0] = temp0;
    array[r][1] = temp1;

    return i + 1;
}

void quickSort(int **array, int p, int r){
    int q;
    if (p < r){
        q = Partition(array, p, r);
        quickSort(array, p, q - 1);
        quickSort(array, q + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually that means there's an infinite recursion. I suggest printing the value of `q` before calling the nested quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you always do the first half (array, p, q - 1) first. That can lead to stack overflow. Instead always do the smallest of the two subarrays first and force tail recursion.

```
void quickSort(int **array, int p, int r){
    while (r - p >= 1){
        int q = Partition(array, p, r);

        if ((q - 1) - p <= r - (q + 1)){
            quicksort(array, p, q - 1);

            // Prepare for tail recursion
            p = q + 1;
        }
        else {
            quicksort(array, q + 1, r);

            // Prepare for tail recursion
            r = q - 1;
       }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, one can prove that the maximum number of recursive calls on the stack is log_{2}(n).

Comment: This might help, and it might not. It depends on whether the compiler implements [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) at the configured optimisation level.

Comment: No. That is irrelevant. The compiler is not allowed to change the order, tail recursion or no tail recursion. It is the order of the two calls that matter.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't use tail recursion, the order of the calls makes no difference to the stack depth at all. How could it?

Comment: @TonyK You are right. I redid my answer to force tail recursion.